# How to Select an Element of An Appended Table With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I built a table by using .append on a div (id = calendarData) that is in the html:

```
 $j('#calendarData').append(
                              '<table class="grid" id="calendar" href="#" style="max-width:1200px"><th colspan="7" align=""center">' +
                              months[currentMonth] + "     " + currentYear + '</div></th><tbody>'+
                              '<tr><td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tues</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thurs</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td>'
                        );
```

Then I added all of the cells to the table:

```
 for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
                            $j('#calendar > tbody:last-child').append(
                                    '</tr><tr>'
                            );
                            for(var j=0;j<7;j++){
                                if(inMonth == 0 && day > getDaysInMonth(startDate.getMonth()-1)){
                                    day = 1;
                                    inMonth = 1;
                                }
                                else if(inMonth == 1 && day > getDaysInMonth(startDate.getMonth())){
                                    day = 1;
                                    inMonth == 2;
                                }
                                $j('#calendar > tbody:last-child').append(
                                        '<td class="square">' + day +  '</td>'
                                );
                                day++;
                            }
                        }
                        $j('#calendarData > tbody:last-child').append(
                              '</tr></tbody></table>'
                        );
```

After this I need to go back and select each td and give it a color if that day is active(determined in a later function) but every time I try to grab it the system comes back with undefined.

Everything from:

```
$j('#calendarData tbody:last-child').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

to

```
var t = document.getElementById("calendar");
var r = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
var d = r.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
d.style.backgroundColor ='green';
```

Every time it throws an Error 'Cannot change Background Color of Undefined"
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post generated HTML table?

Comment: I don't think you need to use the brackets on that collection `d`. You have already designated `d` as a single element `var d = r.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` That is just the first td of the first tr. So try: `d.style.backgroundColor ='green';`

Comment: Why use jquery then dump back to plain js?   $j().style will be undefined because $j() is a jquery object.  Try `$j('').css("background", "green")`

Comment: My apologies. I did try it with d.style.backgroundColor ='green'; and it comes back with "cannot read property 'style' of Undefined"

Comment: freedomn-m - I would love to try that but how do I select one of the elements with the $j('') call you mentioned?

Comment: @TimothyGates you don't have enough code to give you a solid verifiable solution. freedomm-m's conjecture about the td, tr, etc to be a jQuery object is fully warranted. If this is true, then before you try my suggestion, dereference the td or use jQuery. Dereferencing a jQuery object by: `$(selector)[0]`selector is the element you are targeting. Use jQuery by: `$(selector).css('background-color', 'green');`

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure why it's doubling-up the dates in my example, but that's not the point.*

To style the injected HTML class after the fact, you can either add the class ahead of time to the CSS, or you can use jQuery `.css()` to add the styling via jQuery:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.active').css({'color':'maroon','font-weight':'bold','background':'yellow'});
},3000);

$('#calendarData').append('\
 <table class="grid" id="calendar" href="#" style="max-width:1200px">\
  <th colspan="7" align=""center">' +'June'+ "" + '2016' + '</div></th><tbody>\
   <tr><td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tues</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thurs</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td></tr>'
);

setTimeout(function(){
//This mimics your generated / injected code
$('#calendarData > table > tbody').append('\
 <tr><td class="square">1</td><td class="square">2</td><td class="square">3</td><td class="square">4</td><td class="square">5</td><td class="square">6</td><td class="square">7</td></tr>\
 <tr><td class="square">8</td><td class="square">9</td><td class="square">10</td><td class="square active">11</td><td class="square">12</td><td class="square">13</td><td class="square">14</td></tr>\
 <tr><td class="square">15</td><td class="square">16</td><td class="square">17</td><td class="square">18</td><td class="square">19</td><td class="square">20</td><td class="square">21</td></tr>\
 <tr><td class="square">22</td><td class="square">23</td><td class="square">24</td><td class="square">25</td><td class="square">26</td><td class="square">27</td><td class="square">28</td></tr>\
 </tbody></table>'
);
},1500);
```

```css
.square{text-align:center;}
.active{font-style:italic;font-size:larger;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendarData"></div>
```